# Retrieve file that was deleted during the image build

Tags: docker

I have a docker image.
When I use the `docker history` command on the image, I can see

```
85d9bf810d44        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c apk add vim                          26.9MB
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c apk update                           1.78MB
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c rm -f file.txt                           0B
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c a=$(base64 -d < file.txt) && echo $a …   49B
<missing>           9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:98f5646751cb4985…   68B
<missing>           6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>           6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f17f65714f703db90…   5.57MB
```

So there was a file.txt at some point in the image, but it was later removed. I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the content of that file from the image layers.
I have looked into [Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) and all sorts of stuff. Also navigating through Docker's overlay files (as indicated [here](https://blog.pentesteracademy.com/learn-to-analyze-docker-image-with-dive-tool-4cdee4aeef6b)) seemed promising, but I am using macOS and I couldn't find the corresponding directories...

Comment: See [this article on medium](https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612) they mention that if you are on OSX, you need to connect to a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker image save` will export a tarball that contains a tarball per layer.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_save/